# How to set user/password to read emails for Nintex LazyApproval

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, nintex

I am trying to setup Nintex LazyApproval and confused about one thing. When I go to Central Admin I can enable LazyApproval and there it is asking to write an email where they will be sent. I am confused as to how it will be able to read those emails without asking for user/password? There is no option to set user/password to read this email so how Nintex will be able to read them?

Following is the screenshot of Incoming Mail feature in SharePoint 2016. I have set enabled to "Yes".

"Automatic" settings mode is disabled for some reason. In "Directory Management Service" I have selected "No" because I don't need it (I assume it will work even if I set it to No right?)

I have defined email drop folder.

Now If I simply ask infrastructure guy to create one email account in Exchange for e.g. "SharePoint@mycompany.com" and define this email in LazyApproval setting, will it work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note in advance: Nintex Lazy Approval depends on the SharePoint Incoming E-Mail feature, so I'd vote to leave this question open and not to close it as off-topic because of Nintex.

For incoming E-Mail, a subdomain of your existing E-Mail domain will be configured. If your maildomain is `@mycompany.com`, you could use `@sharepoint.mycompany.com` for incoming E-Mail. All E-Mails for this subdomain  will first be accepted by your Exchange-Server and blindly forwarded to SharePoint which is responsible for further processing. [More info on planning Incoming E-Mail](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/incoming-email-planning). For Implementation, follow this [very good step-by-step-guide](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-incoming-email-sharepoint-2010/) - it's for 2010, but still applies for 2013&2016.

If you want to use company's maildomain (`@mycompany.com`), configuration is much more work. I'll describe one possible scenario, even if there are more:

- Create a Mailbox enabled User or Contact in AD&Exchange
- Give it the address which you want to use in Nintex Lazy Approval or in your SharePoint library (e.g. `lazyapproval@mycompany.com`).
- Forward this mail to `lazyapproval@sharepoint.mycompany.com`
- Mail-processing on SharePoint is done like described in the above HowTo
- The biggest disadvantage here is the fact, that you have to configure each Mailaddress manually. In the above mentioned variant with a subdomain, this is simply done in the SharePoint GUi - no mailbox configuration required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your comment is the first time someone has explained clearly how it will work. I didn't understand the blindly forwarded part. Did you mean to say that Exchange server should accept any email received at @sharepoint.mycompany.com and I assume there is not user/password on this email account to read emails correct!? Please also describe company's maildomain (@mycompany.com) process.

Comment: As described in the howto, there is a "Send Connector" for `@sharepoint.company.com` on Exchange which is really stupid: Blindly forward any E-Mail for `@sharepoint.company.com` to SharePoint ("relaying"). Those mails won't get stored in an Exchange Mailbox, so there is nothing which could have a username/password.